# Decomposition of a bipartite graph into complete bipartite graphs by adding the smallest number of edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, decomposition

A bipartite graph $G$ and an integer $K$ is given. I want to decompose $G$ into $K$ complete bipartite graphs by adding the smallest number of edges.

Below is an example of decomposition when $K=2$. The red line indicates an added edge.

[image]
Is there any good (approximation) algorithms?

Comment: How about decomposing $G$ into complete bipartite (1,1) graphs? That is, graph of just two vertices and one edge? There is no need to add any edge.

Comment: If $G$ is decomposed into $K_{1,1}$, the number of decomposed graphs is the number of edges in $G$. The number of decomposed graphs is specified by $K$, so your approach does not work when $K$ and the number of edges are different.

Comment: Do you have any good algorithm in the case of $K=2$?

Comment: No. When $K=1$, there is an obvious algorithm (adding all edges), but when $K \geq 2$, I have no idea.

Comment: Are redundant edges allowed? I.e., Is it allowed that there is an edge in the original graph from one component to another component?